# Surround input text with slash or backslash

Tags: regex, path, pcre

I am trying to surround input string with either `\` or `/`. The input string can only take one of the following forms. The first one is an empty string.

```
path
/path
\path
path/
path\
/path/
\path\
```

I am trying with `^[\\\/]?|[\\\/]?$`. It works for the first four. The later four will have double slash or backslash with this regex. I know why this is happening but don't have any idea on how to fix it. I am using PCRE. I want the output to be `/` when the input is empty and `/path/` for all others.

Current output:

```
/
/path/
/path/
/path/
/path//
/path//
/path//
/path//
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5oxURH/1)
I am only using the multiline flag for convenience.

EDIT: I have updated the solution by @the-fourth-bird to also replace `/` or `\` that are in between.

[Updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/dyZu7T/2) : `^[\\\/]?|[\\\/]+|(?<![\\\/])[\\\/]?$`

EDIT 2: Even better by `u/whereIsMyBroom` over at [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/regex/comments/uvdtnc/surround_input_text_with_slash_or_backslash/).

[regex](https://regex101.com/r/5oxURH/3) : `^[\\\/]?|[\\\/]|(?<![\\\/])$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might write the pattern asserting not `/` or `\` before the last slash using a negative lookbehind `(?<![\\\/]`

```
^[\\\/]?|(?<![\\\/])[\\\/]?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dyZu7T/1)

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Can you please elaborate on how this fixes the issue?

Comment: @FrankShrestha Hi there, adding the negative lookbehind here prevents also matching the *position* when there already is a forward or backslash at the end of the string. Without the lookbehind, it will match a position where there is a forward or backslash at the end of the string, resulting in double slashes after the replacement (that you don't want).